# ajp connector to set packet size in tomcat 5.0.3

Tags: ajp, tomcat5

I have tomcat 5.0.3, in the link its mentioned that the attribute is availiable for tomcat 5.5 onwards.

The attribute packetSize is only available in Tomcat 5.5.20+ and 6.0.2+.

how do increase the packetsize in tomcat 5.0.3.??